# Better practice to modularize code in mixins? Or just put all the code directly into the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, models, mixins

The title kind of says it all.   I prefer to modularize code into mixins and include them into the model. Other people like to put the code directly into the model, potentially growing the models into MOUS's, models of unusual size.

I'm wondering what you guys do/what's better practice out there in dev land.

Comment: Is the code in question going to be useful for more than one model?

Comment: Most of the time no.  I was mainly doing it to modularize related model code and keep our models smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modularizing code as a means to encapsulate independent concerns or behaviors is a good practice, but be careful of correlating short class definitions with “small” objects. The “size” of an object is better measured by the surface area exposed to other objects; in the case of Ruby, methods that are not marked protected or private are a great way of measuring this.

You must also be aware of and account for objects that are tightly coupled to other objects. Modules can help this when used as mixins, but that is not always the case. ActiveRecord breaks behavior into mixins for easy composition (e.g. Validations, Callbacks, and Dirty Tracking), but the `Base` object combines these in a way that makes ActiveRecord models tightly coupled to the underlying codebase.

This is not always a bad thing. David Heinemeier Hansson (@dhh) makes a compelling case for why this sort of “violation” can sometimes create very useful, beneficial interfaces and objects.

In practice, I avoid delegating much additional behavior to ActiveRecord models. When additional behavior is necessary, more specific objects can be wrapped around the model, enhancing them while separating the behavior and code. For example:

```
class UserDecorator
  attr_reader :user
  delegate :first_name, :last_name, to: :user

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

`name` is a pretty common method to be on a `User` object, but the behavior doesn't relate to anything that is persisted. By adding `user#name` to the public interface of an ActiveRecord object, there is an implicit expectation that `user#name=` also exists, and that these map to a datastore. By moving even simple methods like this to a more appropriate object, the interface is clearer, more extensible, and more readily tested.

Note: If you have zero other methods defined on `User`, and you're not already using Decorators, it would probably make more sense to start by defining the `name` method on `User` and extracting it later as complexity is added. Reaching for the most complex solution is a surefire way to build a needlessly complicated application. ;)

Comment: Thanks much for your detailed reply.  That's very interesting. Decorators seem to have a lot of use. It does seems like they have the same coupling issues as inheritance though right?  Except instead of parent model->child class, the decorator is the class on top and the model is sort of the power bottom? 

Where do you like to keep your decorator's in the rails app file structure?  In the Lib folder?    
   
Def agreed about:  `Reaching for the most complex solution is a surefire way to build a needlessly complicated application.'  I would work with you any day :)

Comment: A decorator is just one example of an interface on top of your models, but yes, they are quite useful sometimes. I put decorators in `app/decorators`. Inheritance is not strongly correlated with coupling, so I'm not sure I follow your point.

Comment: This is an AWESOME answer. Thanks for making this place great.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer. I'm still a little noobish so I'm learning as I go and this was very informative and thought provoking. Wish I could award more than one vote!

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I have been moving essentially all business logic out of the models and into plain old Ruby objects - which I guess is the service approach to things. I let the POROs stand alone as full citizens in my apps - I don't mix them back in.

Comment: I like that a lot.  That seems to be the consensus on /r/rails as well.

Comment: I'm also pretty rapid about keeping my controllers homicidally thin - both because I think it's good practice and also because I despise controller tests in RSpec (so painful). Also, I'm recently working on having absolutely zero model access in my views of any kind at all.

Comment: Are your controllers in danger?  Just kidding.   Everywhere I asked this question the consensus was pretty much POROS are the answer.  They seem to attempt to mitigate the 'God object' problem with these massive classes that rails encourages bloating up the place.

Here's my /r/rails post.  There's actually a really interesting post in there about 'God Objects'.

https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/4a3z2f/better_practice_to_modularize_code_in_mixins_or/

Comment: Good question on both sites and lots of interesting answers. And, yes, my controllers live in mortal fear all the time - just the way I like it!